# Django sphinx works only after app restart

Tags: django, search, full-text-search, sphinx, django-sphinx

I've set up django-sphinx in my project, which works perfectly only for some time. Later it always returns empty result set. Surprisingly restarting django app fixes it. And search works again but again only for short time (or very limiter number of queries). Heres my sphinx.conf:

```
source src_questions
{
    # data source
    type        = mysql
    sql_host    = xxxxxx
    sql_user    = xxxxxx #replace with your db username
    sql_pass    = xxxxxx #replace with your db password
    sql_db      = xxxxxx #replace with your db name
    # these two are optional
    sql_port    = xxxxxx
    #sql_sock   = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

    # pre-query, executed before the main fetch query
    sql_query_pre   = SET NAMES utf8

    # main document fetch query
    sql_query       =       SELECT q.id AS id, q.title AS title, q.tagnames AS tags, q.html AS text, q.level AS level \
                            FROM question AS q \
                            WHERE q.deleted=0 \

    # optional - used by command-line search utility to display document information
    sql_query_info  = SELECT title, id, level FROM question WHERE id=$id

    sql_attr_uint   = level
}

index questions {
    # which document source to index
    source      = src_questions

    # this is path and index file name without extension
    # you may need to change this path or create this folder
    path            = /home/rafal/index/index_questions
    # docinfo (ie. per-document attribute values) storage strategy
    docinfo     = extern

    # morphology
    morphology  = stem_en

    # stopwords file
    #stopwords  = /var/data/sphinx/stopwords.txt

    # minimum word length
    min_word_len    = 3

    # uncomment next 2 lines to allow wildcard (*) searches
    min_infix_len = 1
    enable_star = 1

    # charset encoding type
    charset_type    = utf-8
}

# indexer settings
indexer
{
    # memory limit (default is 32M)
    mem_limit   = 64M
}

# searchd settings
searchd
{
    # IP address on which search daemon will bind and accept
    # optional, default is to listen on all addresses,
    # ie. address = 0.0.0.0
    address     = 127.0.0.1

    # port on which search daemon will listen
    port        = 3312

    # searchd run info is logged here - create or change the folder
    log     = ../log/sphinx.log

    # all the search queries are logged here
    query_log   = ../log/query.log

    # client read timeout, seconds
    read_timeout    = 5

    # maximum amount of children to fork
    max_children    = 30

    # a file which will contain searchd process ID
    pid_file    = searchd.pid

    # maximum amount of matches this daemon would ever retrieve
    # from each index and serve to client
    max_matches = 1000
}
```

and heres my search part from views.py:

```
content = Question.search.query(keywords)
    if level:
        content = content.filter(level=level)#level is array of integers
```

There are no errors in any logs, it just isnt returning any results. I have set 'indexer --rotate --all' to be run every 5 mins in cron, and searchd is up and running all time.
All help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of sphinx? django-sphinx? sphinxsearch api? python?

Anyway, try to remove the `indexer` from the `cron` & see if this problem persists. Let me know how this goes.